# Set time zone programatically in query in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I've got a query which holds data about a 'group' where each row has a timestamp with timezone ~(so utc).

Each group belongs to a building which has the timezone for which that building belongs to. Data example is as follows:

| id | timestamp | value | building_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2023-02-01 23:00:00+00 | 5 | 1234 |
| 5 | 2023-02-02 00:00:00+00 | 10 | 1234 |

| id | time_zone |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | Europe/Paris |

I'm trying to write a query where I return the data for a given group between two certain days, but within the timezone of the building.

So for example using the data above, if I'm querying the building in Paris I will pass in a date from '2023-02-02T00:00' (this is the local time) and this will then retrieve the data from the table starting from 2023-02-01T23:00:00 as this is the UTC equivilent for midnight in Paris.

I've got the following query where I set the time zone for the session and it uses that when querying the data. However I would like to set the `TIME ZONE` programatically as depending what group I'm querying it could be in any time zone so would like to get the time zone from the building record:

```
SET TIMEZONE to (SELECT time_zone AS tz
    FROM energy.building
    WHERE id = (SELECT building_id FROM energy."group" WHERE id = '06A20-026:1'));

SELECT *
FROM data."group"
WHERE id = '06A20-026:1' AND "timestamp" >= '2023-02-02' AND "timestamp" < '2023-02-03'                                
ORDER BY "timestamp" ASC
```

But I'm getting a syntax error on the first line `SET TIMEZONE to **(**SELECT`

What is the correct structure I need to assign the TIMEZONE from a query result?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to do that with some dynamic SQL using EXECUTE in a plpgsql function I think.

However, you can get a local timestamp based on your group's timezone.

```
=> SELECT * FROM tt;
┌───────────────────────────────┐
│               t               │
├───────────────────────────────┤
│ 2023-03-02 13:26:52.646649+00 │
└───────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)

=> SELECT * FROM zones;
┌───────────────┐
│       z       │
├───────────────┤
│ Europe/London │
│ Europe/Paris  │
└───────────────┘
(2 rows)

=> SELECT tt.t, tt.t at time zone zones.z AS local_time
FROM tt CROSS JOIN zones;
┌───────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────┐
│               t               │         local_time         │
├───────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────┤
│ 2023-03-02 13:26:52.646649+00 │ 2023-03-02 13:26:52.646649 │
│ 2023-03-02 13:26:52.646649+00 │ 2023-03-02 14:26:52.646649 │
└───────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────┘
(2 rows)
```

Comment: That could work if I can't do it the other way. I one thing that is missing from this though is that using `SET TIMEZONE TO ...` returns the offset as well e.g. `2023-02-02 00:00:00+01` which is quite useful, rather than just the local time